# Acr.UserDialogs PCL error

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

In my `Xamarin` cross-platform native application i try to use loading indicator from `Acr.UserDialogs(ver 5.3)`. In a portable project I try this code:

```cs
public bool IsLoading
    {
        get { return _isLoading; }

        set
        {
            _isLoading = value;
            if (value)
            {
                UserDialogs.Instance.ShowLoading("Loading...", MaskType.Black);
            }
            else
            {
                UserDialogs.Instance.HideLoading();
            }
        }
    }
```

In main activity:

```cs
if (UserDialogs.Instance == null)
{
    UserDialogs.Init(this);
}
```

As a result I catch following exception:

> System.ArgumentException: This is the PCL library, not the platform
>   library.  You must install the nuget package in your main
>   executable/application project

[Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYpJA.png)

Acr installed in portable project and in droid project:[Acr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEHTf.png)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: please edit your question to include the exception message as formatted text, not a screenshot.  Screenshots cannot be indexed by search engines.

Comment: Could you try removing the `if (UserDialogs.Instance == null)` statement and just leave `UserDialogs.Init(this);` in `MainActivity.OnCreate()`?

Comment: I remove `if (UserDialogs.Instance == null)`. New error: System.MissingMethodException: Method 'UserDialogs.Init' not found.

Comment: I dont know what was the problem but I had same crazy error, i tried everything delete bin, obj, temp, rebuild, reinstall packages, none of them helped but just changing the line worked :) simply copy paste to another line in mainactivity

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem but in *iOS*. This is how I resolved the issue. Please make sure that below dependencies must be installed in each project according to this [link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Acr.UserDialogs/6.3.3) along with `Acr.UserDialogs`(I also recommend to check dependencies as per your Acr.UserDialogs lib version from given link).

**All Frameworks**

```
Splat (>= 1.6.2 && < 2.0.0)
```

**MonoAndroid 1.0**

```
AndHUD (>= 1.2.0 && < 2.0.0)
Splat (>= 1.6.2 && < 2.0.0)
Acr.Support (>= 2.1.0 && < 3.0.0)
Xamarin.Android.Support.Design (>= 23.3.0 && < 25.0.0)
```

**UAP 10.0**

```
Splat (>= 1.6.2 && < 2.0.0)
Coding4Fun.Toolkit.Controls (>= 2.1.8 && < 3.0.0)
```

**Xamarin.iOS 1.0**

```
Splat (>= 1.6.2 && < 2.0.0)
Acr.Support (>= 2.1.0 && < 3.0.0)
```

> Don't forget to install `Acr.UserDialogs` **in each project along with
>   portable project**.
>
> **NOTE :-** Check this [link](https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs) to setup the library(Specially for Android this library requires initialization of `UserDialogs` in main
>   Activity).

Answer (score 1):

I solve it by uninstalling Acr.UserDialogs from all projects. Install Acr.UserDialog in Android project. Clean and Rebuild Solution and install Acr.UserDialog in Portable project.

Further use it in Portable project like that.

```
UserDialogs.Instance.ShowSuccess("Some Text");
```

Comment: But i'm not sure that it would work on different platforms correctly,